# Replace clicked item with main div text (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, click

To be honest, i am not very good at jquery, so maybe i will find help here. However, my code does work, but it works only once. When i am trying to click again - nothing happens.

**HTML**

```
<li class="selected">All numbers</li>

<br/>

<li class="item">1</li>
<li class="item">2</li>
<li class="item">3</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("li.item").click(function() {
  $("li.selected").replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

**Question:**

How can i make this script work all the time, not only once? As i said before, i am not good with jquery, and i cant find proper way to fix this problem.

**Jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/yLgx6xxo/

Comment: `$("li.selected").empty().html($(this).text());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `text()` instead of 'replacing the div'.

The reason your example *didn't* work was because you were replacing:

```
 <li class="selected">All numbers</li>
```

with

```
 1
```

So when you came to replacing the next, jquery wasn't finding the `"selected"` div, so no replacement was occurring.

---

By instead using the `text()`, your only replacing the actual 'text' part of the div,

So instead,

```
 <li class="selected">All numbers</li>
```

becomes

```
 <li class="selected">1</li>
```

---

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/yLgx6xxo/1/)

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  $("li.selected").text($(this).text());
});
```

```css
li.selected, li.item { list-style-type: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="selected">All numbers</li>

<br/>

<li class="item">1</li>
<li class="item">2</li>
<li class="item">3</li>
```

Comment: @Tauras: I hope you are able to understand as to *why* as well.